# Hostname mapping to directory in ASP.NET / WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I've read many posts that relate to this but have not found a solution as yet.

I have a set of WCF service files (*.svc) in a directory "/api" in an ASP.NET project

I have pointed both api.mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com at the server running the project.

Currently, to reach the .svc files I have to construct the url like this:

api.mydomain.com/api/[servicefilename].svc

Ideally I'd like to find some changes that I could make to web.config that would allow the use of this url instead, for that same resource:

api.mydomain.com/[servicefilename].svc

One constraint: I cannot make changes to IIS configuration because I'm using Elasticbeanstalk deployment to EC2.

Thanks for any help with this...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WCF 4, you don't even need an svc file.

Put something like this in your web.config

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="Service.svc" service="MyService" />
    </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Any request to api.mydomain.com/service.svc will call your service implementation "MyService"

[This blog post](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/fileless-activation-of-wcf-service-in-net-4-0/) has some more examples including usage of a Service Host Factory, and extensionless URLs

Comment: This is very interesting but doesn't seem to address the question directly (unless I am misunderstanding). What I'm after is a way to map the api.* hostname to the /api directory in the project.

Comment: @Jimmy_m is there a reason you need to solve your issue that way? Why can't you place your svc file at the root?  I'm suggesting you don't use svc files at all

Comment: Where would I define the service endpoints & behavior if not in a svc file?

Comment: I'm intrigued by what you're saying btw. My goal is to expose the api endpoints at api.domain.com with expected REST urls (ie without extensions) so I likely have several configuration changes to make. I'm reviewing the blog post currently...

Comment: Ok, I've succeeded in making the approach from the [blog post](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/fileless-activation-of-wcf-service-in-net-4-0/) work in the local dev environment.  So, this means that the service is available at http:// localhost:2511/servicename. This means that upon publication it would also be available at http:// www . domain.com/servicename (ignore the spaces). Now the next challenge is to make it available only at api. and not www. if possible.

Comment: @Jimmy_m I'm assuming you figured out how to use the Service Host Factory to activate your service etc?  And I think I misunderstood the subdomain part of you question.  I would personally have the www as one website, and the api pointing to a separate service.  If you must have them together, you may need to look at using the Route Table

Comment: A "hack" would involve doing a subdomain check in each method and throwing a "404" - but I think you could do something equivalent in the Route Tables

Comment: >I think you could do something equivalent in the Route Tables< that's exactly what I'm after